# Scroll bar on JFrame in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, scrollpane

So I have a JFrame of size 500x500 on which I am drawing a line from (0,200) until (100000,200) using g.drawLine(x,y). The problem is I cannot see the entire line as there is no scroll bar. Could someone please tell me how to have a scroll bar in this particular situation to see the entire line upto the point (100000,200).

Comment: As no one wants to scroll that far, what [*actual problem*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/163188) are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

While I have [usability concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457705/scroll-bar-on-jframe-in-java-swing#comment62415922_37457705), the example below illustrates how to implement the [`Scrollable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface as discussed in [*How to Use Scroll Panes: Implementing a Scrolling-Savvy Client*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable). Note in particular how the result of `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` differs from the result of `getPreferredSize()`. The unit and block increments make paging slightly easier, too.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37460185/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(new DrawingPanel()));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        private static final int W = 100_000;
        private static final int H = 400;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(W, H);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2);
            g.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 4, 0, 3 * getHeight() / 4);
            g.drawLine(W - 1, getHeight() / 4, W - 1, 3 * getHeight() / 4);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return new Dimension(640, H);
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            if (orientation == SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL) {
                return W / 10;
            } else {
                return 10;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            if (orientation == SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL) {
                return W / 10;
            } else {
                return 10;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us the code? Since it's hard to know without seeing it, however on the top of my head I think you should just create one and add it to your JFrame like so:

```
 JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(); // Example with a JTextArea,
         depends on what you have, as I said, we need to see the code

 JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta); //Add it to the component 
    needed, in your case the drawn line i guess

 jFrame.add(sp); //Add it to the frame
```

Ande before adding it, you can manipulate the size:

```
sp.setColumnHeaderView(new JLabel("header column"));

sp.setRowHeaderView(new JLabel("header row"));

sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
```